# Mongoose password update using await

Tags: javascript, mongoose, async-await

```js
exports.reset = async function (req, res) {
  const _id = req.body._id;
  let hashed = await hash("123456");
  console.log("hashed", hashed); //hashed $2b$10$QgZqLrYNuaX64IFg5VFsC
  UserModel.updateOne(
    { _id: _id },
    { $set: { password: hashed } },
    (err, doc) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      console.log("doc:", doc.password); //doc: undefined ? why
      res.send({ msg: "update sucess", code: "1" });
    }
  );
};
```

Hi I am trying to reset password after hashing it by using await, but even the result is success and the hashed password appeared before `updateOne` but doc.password show "undefined", and the password did update. Can anyone tell me what did I do wrong ?

Comment: I would guess that updating a password would not return the password for security reasons. Did you say the password is updated successfully in the database?

Comment: HI thank you for reply , no the password didnot get update even the return msg said "update succes"

Comment: You send  `"update sucess"` even though an error occurres. You should send a different message `if (err)`

Comment: A few thoughts:

- Is req.body._id defined
- Is it a string? Is Mongoose expecting an ObjectId?
- In your if(err) you should send a fail response, and move the success into an else block

Comment: @Thomas you are right ! but this is still weird since no error occures and doc.password is undefined even hashed got value

Comment: The second parameter of the callback is a updateWriteOpResult containing n, ok and nModified. It doesn't contain the written data.
 https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.updateOne